# Getting running total in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can i calculate the running total from below query

**Query**

```
SELECT
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo as [Invoice No] ,
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate as [Invoice Date],
  Suppliers.SupplierName,
  dbo.Restaurants.Name as [Restaurant Name],
  CONVERT(decimal(9, 2), SUM(RequisitionDetails.ReceivedQuantity * RequisitionDetails.UnitPrice)) AS Debit
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders
INNER JOIN dbo.Requisitions
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.RequisitionID = dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID
INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants
  ON dbo.Requisitions.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID
INNER JOIN dbo.Suppliers
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.SupplierID = dbo.Suppliers.SupplierID
INNER JOIN dbo.Categories
  ON dbo.Requisitions.CategoryID = dbo.Categories.CategoryID
INNER JOIN dbo.PurchaseInvoices
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID = dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceID
INNER JOIN dbo.RequisitionDetails
  ON dbo.RequisitionDetails.RequisitionID = dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID
GROUP BY dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID,
         dbo.Restaurants.Name,
         dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate,
         dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo,
         Suppliers.SupplierName
ORDER BY dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo
```

**Query Out Put**

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+--------+
| Invoice No | Invoice Date | Supplier Name | Restaurant Name |  Debit |
+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+--------+
|          1 | 8/26/2016    | supplier1     | restaurant 1    |  92.00 |
|          2 | 8/27/2016    | supplier1     | restaurant 2    |  47.00 |
+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+--------+
```

**The desired out put should be like below**

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+--------+---------+
| Invoice No | Invoice Date | Supplier Name | Restaurant Name |  Debit | Balance |
+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+--------+---------+
|          1 | 8/26/2016    | supplier1     | restaurant 1    |  92.00 |   92.00 |
|          2 | 8/27/2016    | supplier1     | restaurant 2    |  47.00 |  139.00 |
+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+--------+---------+
```

How can i achieve this? to get running total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` operator or `Correlated sub-query` to find running total

```
;with result as 
(
SELECT
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo as [Invoice No] ,
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate as [Invoice Date],
  Suppliers.SupplierName,
  dbo.Restaurants.Name as [Restaurant Name],
  CONVERT(decimal(9, 2), SUM(RequisitionDetails.ReceivedQuantity * RequisitionDetails.UnitPrice)) AS Debit
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders
INNER JOIN dbo.Requisitions
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.RequisitionID = dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID
INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants
  ON dbo.Requisitions.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID
INNER JOIN dbo.Suppliers
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.SupplierID = dbo.Suppliers.SupplierID
INNER JOIN dbo.Categories
  ON dbo.Requisitions.CategoryID = dbo.Categories.CategoryID
INNER JOIN dbo.PurchaseInvoices
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID = dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceID
INNER JOIN dbo.RequisitionDetails
  ON dbo.RequisitionDetails.RequisitionID = dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID
GROUP BY dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID,
         dbo.Restaurants.Name,
         dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate,
         dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo,
         Suppliers.SupplierName
)
SELECT * 
FROM   result a 
       OUTER apply (SELECT Sum([debit]) 
                    FROM   result b 
                    WHERE  a.[invoice no] >= b.[invoice no]) cs (balance)
```

Unfortunately you are still in `Sql Server 2008`, in `Sql Server 2012+` we have `Sum() Over(Order by)` aggregate window function to calculate running which is way faster than above method

**Update:** For `SQL SERVER 2012+` use this

```
;with result as
(
SELECT
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo as [Invoice No] ,
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate as [Invoice Date],
  Suppliers.SupplierName,
  dbo.Restaurants.Name as [Restaurant Name],
  CONVERT(decimal(9, 2), SUM(RequisitionDetails.ReceivedQuantity * RequisitionDetails.UnitPrice)) AS Debit
FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders
INNER JOIN dbo.Requisitions
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.RequisitionID = dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID
INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurants
  ON dbo.Requisitions.RestaurantID = dbo.Restaurants.RestaurantID
INNER JOIN dbo.Suppliers
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.SupplierID = dbo.Suppliers.SupplierID
INNER JOIN dbo.Categories
  ON dbo.Requisitions.CategoryID = dbo.Categories.CategoryID
INNER JOIN dbo.PurchaseInvoices
  ON dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID = dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceID
INNER JOIN dbo.RequisitionDetails
  ON dbo.RequisitionDetails.RequisitionID = dbo.Requisitions.RequisitionID
GROUP BY dbo.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderID,
         dbo.Restaurants.Name,
         dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate,
         dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo,
         Suppliers.SupplierName
)
SELECT *, sum(Debit) over(Order by [invoice no]) as balance
FROM   result a
```

Comment: i am using Sql Server 2012

Comment: @Ayman - Then why is your question tagged with `SQL SERVER 2008` :o

Comment: @Ayman - check the update

Comment: i got this error Incorrect syntax near 'result'.

Comment: thanks but i still get the error

Comment: same Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'result'.

Comment: working now when i changed result to cte thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the SUM() OVER( ORDER BY  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
Try the below select statement:

```
SELECT
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo as [Invoice No] ,
  dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceDate as [Invoice Date],
  Suppliers.SupplierName,
  dbo.Restaurants.Name as [Restaurant Name],
  CONVERT(decimal(9, 2), SUM(RequisitionDetails.ReceivedQuantity * RequisitionDetails.UnitPrice)) AS Debit,
  CONVERT(decimal(9,2), SUM(SUM(RequisitionDetails.ReceivedQuantity * RequisitionDetails.UnitPrice)) OVER(ORDER BY dbo.PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceNo ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) ) AS Balance
FROM ...
```

Comment: Question is tagged with `SQL SERVER 2008` which does not support `sum() over(Order by)`

Comment: I got this error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: I've added an edit, I think it was missing a closing bracket for the `CONVERT()`.
Tell me if it does/ doesn't work/ if you are using `SQL Server 2008`.